# Find the volume enclosed by terrain and a certain sea level

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have a terrain, which is represented by  [one mesh with a lot of polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh) as shown below:

[image]

This terrain will be cut by a plane at a certain level. So there are volumes of the terrains that are located above the plane ( cut volume), and volumes that are located below the plane ( fill volume).

The question is, how do I obtain the cut/ fill volume? My current approach is simply take one mesh at a time, and then form a tetrahedron with the plane, and compute the volume. **But this is slow**. Is there other better approach?

One approach that I have in mind, is to try to form Bezier surface for the terrain, and then try to use integration to compute the volume. But I don't know how to proceed with this. Any idea?

**Edit: Terminology updated**

Comment: I'd first start by figuring out what interpolating function(s) were used to create that mesh.

Comment: @J.M., no interpolation function were used; they were obtained from field survey, or at least this is the assumption I have to make.

Comment: Ah, so you have an array of coordinate triples as data? Then Bézier isn't what you want (that would be within the data as the convex hull, not interpolate through it). Would there be sharp bumps/peaks/valleys in the data you have?

Comment: @J.M., there will be. But if Bezier surface is not a good choice, why is it not a good choice? And is there any other alternatives that I can use?

Comment: As I said, Bézier treats your data as a convex hull instead of points to interpolate. Bicubic interpolation is standard fare, but without seeing what the data looks like, I don't want to give a definite recommendation.

Comment: @J.M., are you saying that Bezier is not a good choice because all the hill and valleys characteristics will not make it into the function because Bezier treats data as a convex hull?

Comment: Just to show how a Bézier surface works, here's some old stuff I did in *Mathematica*: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4930/ . Here, the "teapot" does not pass through the points, but the points do control the shape of the "teapot". For the purpose of finding volumes, this isn't what you want.

Comment: Terminology note: Your terrain is not made of "a lot of meshes", it is *one* mesh made of a lot of *polygons* (triangles in this case).

Comment: @Rahul, terminology updated.

Answer (score 1):

How close do you have to be?

Can you just find the center of the each triangle in space then divide the cutting plane into a 2d grid and do a series of rectangular volume calculations using the length and width of the grid section and the average height of the triangle midpoint above/below that grid section?

Comment: Yes, if this is actual survey data, then chopping it up into many tall, thin "straws" or "french fries" (triangular prisms or rectangular boxes or hexagonal prisms) -- either one for each point, or one for each triangle -- is going to be the best you can do.

Comment: yes, that's my strategy now. But I don't really like it because I have too many polygons, too many points and the calculation is slow. I'm looking for a more efficient way to doing things.

Comment: if you average the height (z) of the triangle centers for a certain x,y region you can get a faster estimate of the volume. For example if you break the cutting plane into four quadrants and find the height of the triangle centers above that quadrant then you can just use the x,y lengths and the z height for an estimate of the volume. There is some error when the triangle of the polygon go over the border between quadrants but you can break the plane into smaller segments to minimize this. thus it is a tradeoff between speed and accuracy.

Comment: basically you can extend this ( http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheIntegralMeanValueTheoremAnIllustration/ ) into the third dimension.

Comment: other than that the algorithm is data parallel and XNA is on the .net platform so you could use the task parallel library to try and speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to compute the volume under (or above) each triangle. The volume from a triangle to the plane *z=0* can be computed as:

```
V  =  (z1+z2+z3)(x1y2-x2y1+x2y3-x3y2+x3y1-x1y3)/6
```

In python:

```
def volume_under_triangle(triangle):
    p1, p2, p3 = triangle
    x1, y1, z1 = p1
    x2, y2, z2 = p2
    x3, y3, z3 = p3
    return (z1+z2+z3)*(x1*y2-x2*y1+x2*y3-x3*y2+x3*y1-x1*y3)/6
```

Full explanation [here](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath393.htm). You will need to adapt the formula for *z=sea_level* by substracting *sea_level* to the *z* of each point. For a given sea level, the sign of the volume will be positive or negative depending on whether you numbered the points clockwise or
counter-clockwise.

As some of your triangles will be above sea level and others under it, you will need to keep a consistent, clockwise or counter-clockwise point ordering. You can run this computation for all your triangles, then you add the positive volumes together to get the cut or fill volume (depending on your ordering) and the negative ones to get the other one.

As to how efficient is this, I've made a basic test that computes the volume of a surface with ~70k triangles using Python and it took ~2seconds running on mid-tier 6yo hardware, however I guess it could be improved quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you graph a subsection of terrain by volume? Doing it by hand I imagine would be painstakingly long. Maybe use a computer to iterate through the data. Something like:

```
[i for in n if y_1 ==, >, <.... #for every axis, you get the gist
```

The shape of the plane for your cut will also matter I guess but for simplicity of your just doing a rectangular plane as a cut i would use comprehension as above so when you set your plane height, length and width you only log the data points that correspond to that value of y. Iterated over all the data points in the ${x, y, z}$ axis should give you your cubic volume right, above and below if you know the maximum heights of all points?